# Index out of bounds error in prediction step of keras/python

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, keras

I am trying to run predictions on timeseries data using Keras/Theanos backend in python where I am taking factors from past few days to predict for next day.I am able to generate predictions using other algorithms like xgboost but wanted to try ANN but got stuck with index out of bounds error during prediction step

Part of code is something like this:

```
clfnn = Sequential()
clfnn.add(Dense(32, input_dim=9,init='uniform',activation='tanh'))
clfnn.add(Dense(9,init='uniform',activation='tanh'))
clfnn.add(Dense(1,activation='tanh'))
clfnn.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])

imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)
imp.fit(testsample[factorsnew])
testsample[factorsnew]=imp.transform(testsample[factorsnew])
validationsample[factorsnew]=imp.transform(validationsample[factorsnew])

models={'prediction':clfnn}

for key in models:
    try:
        models[key].fit(testsample[factorsnew].as_matrix(),testsample['returnranksnn'].as_matrix(),verbose=1) 
        validationsample[key]=models[key].predict_proba(validationsample[factorsnew].as_matrix(),verbose=1)[:,1]           
    except:
        print sys.exc_info()[0]
        print sys.exc_info()[1]
        pass
```

The model somehow seems to fit without any problems but prediction step is giving an error. Output looks something like this:

```
Epoch 1/10
32240/32240 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.2506 - acc: 0.5980     
Epoch 2/10
32240/32240 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.2504 - acc: 0.6054     
Epoch 3/10
32240/32240 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.2504 - acc: 0.6069     
Epoch 4/10
32240/32240 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.2505 - acc: 0.6028     
Epoch 5/10
32240/32240 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.2504 - acc: 0.6015     
Epoch 6/10
32240/32240 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.2503 - acc: 0.6067     
Epoch 7/10
32240/32240 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.2504 - acc: 0.6020     
Epoch 8/10
32240/32240 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.2505 - acc: 0.5999     
Epoch 9/10
32240/32240 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.2504 - acc: 0.6040     
Epoch 10/10
32240/32240 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.2505 - acc: 0.6024     

32/40 [=======================>......] - ETA: 0s<type 'exceptions.IndexError'>
index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1
```

Note: The data is normalized without any NaNs and predictor variable is int type having only two outcomes 0 or 1 and outcome should be just a probablity number

Tried changing settings of the optimizers, different factors in data but in vain. Majority of the samples get stuck at **32**/40 or **32**/*** as you see in the output. Any ideas on what I am missing here? Thanks

Comment: Look up keras docs on what ```predict_proba``` returns. The error is within this line: ```validationsample[key]=models[key].predict_proba(validationsample[factorsnew].as_matrix(),verbose=1)[:,1]```. It might be as easy as removing the indexing.

Comment: thanks @sascha. predict_proba does give me probability results which I required.When I tried removing the index, though I don't get an exception, I get something like ' 32/40 [=======================>......] - ETA: 0s2'. I do get output this time but I think the results are based on incomplete prediction

Comment: Could you include the error traceback in your question? Also, what do `validationsample[factorsnew].as_matrix().shape` and `models[key].predict_proba(validationsample[factorsnew].as_matrix(),verbose=1).shape` give?